# Allow / Disable speicifc copy ctor and assignment operations for templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am wondering if it possible to achieve something with templates.
What I want to do is allow specific 'copy ctors and assigment operators' from one template to another and disable others.

I think I managed only one of the things that I want so I am providing the class below.
For copy ctors or assignment operators I want to be able to do the below

- `Foo<false>` to `Foo<false>` always OK
- `Foo<true>` should only be allowed to copied or assigned to `Foo<false>`

I am not sure if it is possible...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<bool Owner>
class Foo
{
    static constexpr bool owner_ = Owner;

public: 
    Foo() {std::cout << "ctor\n";}
    Foo operator=(const Foo& foo) { std::cout << "assignment\n";}
    Foo(const Foo& foo) { std::cout << "copy ctor \n"; }

    template <bool U>
    Foo( const Foo<U>& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor2 \n"; 
    }

    template <bool U>
    Foo<false>& operator=( const Foo<U>& other)
    {
        std::cout << "assignment 2 \n"; 
        return *this;
    }

    template < bool B_ = Owner, typename = std::enable_if_t <B_> >
    void bar1() {
        std:cout << "bar1 " << owner_ << "\n";
    }

    void bar2() {std:cout << "bar2 " << owner_ << "\n";}
};
```

At the moment the only thing that I have succeeded is that `operator=` will work for `Foo<false>` = `Foo<true>`.
`Foo<false>` to `Foo<false>` is OK, but that allows all other conversions as well so `Foo<true>` to `Foo<true>` is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Anything is possible in C++.

Your question wasn't 100% clear as to what is the expected behavior for all combinations, but this is easy enough to be trivially adjustable:

```
#include <iostream>

// Helper class

template<bool from, bool to> class ok_to_copy_foos;

// Define all valid conversions as specializations:

template<>
class ok_to_copy_foos<false, false> {

public:
    typedef bool type;
};

template<>
class ok_to_copy_foos<true, false> {

public:
    typedef bool type;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<bool Owner>
class Foo {

public:

    Foo() {}

    template<bool U, typename allow=typename ok_to_copy_foos<U, Owner>::type>
    Foo(const Foo<U> &)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor \n";
    }

    template<bool U, typename allow=typename ok_to_copy_foos<U, Owner>::type>
    Foo &operator=(const Foo<U> &)
    {
        std::cout << "assignment\n";

        return *this;
    }
};

void foo()
{
    Foo<false> f1;
    Foo<true> t1;

    // These ones will compile:
    Foo<false> f2(f1);
    f2=f1;
    f2=t1;

    //   These ones will not compile
    //
    //      t1=f2;
    //  Foo<true> t2(f2);
}
```

EDIT: Looks like it is also be necessary to add an explicit copy constructor and an assignment operator. Deleting the default ones will not be sufficient:

```
Foo(const Foo &o)
{
    typename ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::type dummy;
}

Foo &operator=(const Foo &o)
{
    typename ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::type dummy;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty good but I wonder if there are 2 cases that could also be cought.
That is 
`auto t3(t1);` will work and so will `auto ta = t1;`
Additionally, if I wanted to add some helpful static_assert to say "this is not supported" where would it go ?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally posted the comment prior to completing it. The compiler defined copy constructor and assignement seems to be allowing those two

Comment: Similarly I think the `<false, false>` conversion specialization is not even used but instead the compiler generated function is preferred.

Comment: Heh, to block copy construction via auto, add an explicit copy constructor, updated my answer. Depending on the class members some additional fudging may be needed. This question mentions nothing about `static_assert`. A different approach will be needed to use that; if so this will have to be a new follow-up question.

Comment: Thanks it seems that `operator=` needs that as well
`Foo operator=(const Foo& foo)`
`{`
`typename ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::type dummy;`
`}`

Assuming that this is a form of SFINAE I have to admit I have never seen it being part of a function, always part of the function declaration will have to some reading on it.

Comment: Fair enough, updated the answer again. This is not `SFINAE`. The whole purpose of `SFINAE` is not to abort compilation. Here, you want to bail out. And as far as `static_assert` goes, the basic idea is to add a default template deifnition for `ok_to_copy_foos` that defines a `static constexpr bool value=false;` class member, have the specializations define the value of `true`, and use that as the `static_assert` in `Foo`'s class members.

Comment: Does it have a name or something that I can use so I can read more on it ?

Comment: Well, this is, in general specialization. I guess the name "no-default-template-only-specializations-for-valid-template-parameters" would be as good of a name as anything else...

Comment: Ok upon further look I was able to fully understand what was happening. The way I was trying was to do everything by SFINAE... Now I see that it is possible to completely avoid SFINAE even for the 2 functions and simplify the code a little bit. A live example is over here, https://ideone.com/HJtccx.
However in both your code and the one I provided there is one little thing that does not work and that is `auto f4 = t1`. I guess this was introduced when the explicit copy constructor was added. Any chance to allow something like that ?